# How does boost::uBLAS handle nested products of matrices?

Tags: c++, boost, linear-algebra, ublas, expression-templates

I read an article about the optimisation of nested product of matrices, using dynamic programming, and I wanted to see how it is implemented in boost::uBLAS.

I'm not sure I understood [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/operations_overview.htm) (they talk about it at the very end of the page), but it seems they handle this problem. When you write `R = prod(A, prod(B,C));`, the library computes `A x (B x C)` or `(A x B) x C` depending on the sizes of `A`, `B` and `C`.

How can it be achieved ? How can the library "move the brackets" ? When writing such a code line, I thought the arguments of `prod` would be evaluated, and then the function would be run.

The [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) mentions the notion of expression templates. Is it linked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, expression templates (which you may find under the name "expression trees") are involved.

Basically, `prod` doesn't return the result, but a wrapper object holding the operation (matrix multiply) and pointers to the two inputs.  If `prod` is called with such a wrapper as input, it can apply reordering optimizations.

However, from my reading of that page, no such optimization is applied (it says it honors bracketing structure).